# org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Cannot click on element" in WebDriver(IE9)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

For the first time, I am able to find the element but if I repeat the same step and try to find the element then I am getting following error:

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Cannot click on element (WARNING: The server did >not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 172 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:12:12'
>   System info: host: 'D-315009004', ip: '10.101.160.72', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', >os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_23'
>   Session ID: 863c6fb7-ff23-4f18-9880-a63d36538bc8
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
>   Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, elementScrollBehavior=0, >enablePersistentHover=true, ignoreZoomSetting=false, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, >browserName=internet explorer, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss, >version=9, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, >ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, requireWindowFocus=false, handlesAlerts=true, >initialBrowserUrl="", ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, nativeEvents=true, browserAttachTimeout=0, >ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, takesScreenshot=true}]
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)

Following is the HTML code snippet:

```
<DIV style="Z-INDEX: 9003; POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 1000px; DISPLAY: block; VISIBILITY: visible; TOP: 76px; LEFT: 183px" id=ext-comp-1067 class=" x-window">
<DIV class=x-window-tl>
  <DIV class=x-window-tr>
    <DIV class=x-window-tc>
      <DIV style="MozUserSelect: none; KhtmlUserSelect: none" id=ext-gen452 class="x-window-header x-unselectable x-window-draggable" unselectable="on">
        <DIV id=ext-gen457 class="x-tool x-tool-close">&nbsp;</DIV>
        <SPAN id=ext-gen461 class=x-window-header-text>View/Edit QC</SPAN>
      </DIV>
    </DIV>
  </DIV>
</DIV>
```

where I'm trying to click on `close` icon which is `<DIV id=ext-gen457 class="x-tool x-tool-close">&nbsp;</DIV>`

Comment: please post the html here

Comment: Hi,  PF HTML here:  `<DIV style="Z-INDEX: 9003; POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 1000px; DISPLAY: block; VISIBILITY: visible; TOP: 76px; LEFT: 183px" id=ext-comp-1067 class=" x-window">
<DIV class=x-window-tl>
<DIV class=x-window-tr>
<DIV class=x-window-tc>
<DIV style="MozUserSelect: none; KhtmlUserSelect: none" id=ext-gen452 class="x-window-header x-unselectable x-window-draggable" unselectable="on">
<DIV id=ext-gen457 class="x-tool x-tool-close">&nbsp;</DIV><SPAN id=ext-gen461 class=x-window-header-text>View/Edit QC</SPAN></DIV></DIV></DIV></DIV>`

Comment: In above html, i am trying to find "close" icon using `class=x-tool x-tool-close`.

Comment: Have you tried `div` `close` id using `By.id()` or `By.className()`? You can also post what you have tried

Answer (score 4):

The error is thrown because element isn't visible.

You can use explicit wait for elemtent to be clickable and then click on it like following:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("someid")));
//or try: WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("someid")));
element.click();
```

Or execute javascript on invisible element like following(but which doesn't mimic real user):

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("some_id"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply.
I tried your code but after execution, i am getting "org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException:" exception with "Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for element to be clickable:" message.

Comment: How long does it take element to be clickable, manually? If it's more than 10 seconds, accordingly increase timeout in first line of my above mentioned code.

Comment: Manually it will not take much time. When Application is slow it will take max 2 to 3 seconds. Though i tried by giving 40 seconds time but still i got"org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 40 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: "

Comment: I have even tried modified script but still it did not work.
Any way i have found an alternative i.e 
`Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE).build().perform();`

I know it is not a right answer either but using "Escape", i can close it.

Thanks for the suggestion any way.